# matplotlibにおけるグラフの始点の指定

Tags: python, matplotlib

matplotlibについての質問です．
長さの違う二つのデータ`list1`, `list2`をグラフにしたいです．

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [6, 7, 8]
```

があるとして，

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(list1)
plt.plot(list2)
plt.show()
```

このようににplotすると`list2`のグラフは左詰で出力されると思うのですが，今回は右詰，`list2`が途中(`x=2`)から出力されるようにしたいです．データ毎に表示範囲をしていしたりできるのかなと思ったのですが，方法が分かりませんでした．
もし，グラフを途中から表示させる方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら教えていただけるとありがたいです．よろしくお願いします．

Answer (score 2):

### 方法1: そのデータが x 軸のどこに対応するのか明示的に指定する

[`plt.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) は `plt.plot(xdata, ydata)` の形式で (x, y) 形式のデータをプロットできます。

```
plt.plot(range(0, 5), list1)
plt.plot(range(2, 5), list2)
```

### 方法2: `None` で埋めて長さを揃える

`None` は欠損値扱いされます。

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [None, None, 6, 7, 8]

plt.plot(list1)
plt.plot(list2)
```

Comment: 今回例示したデータに対しては
    plt.plot(range(0, 6), list1)
    plt.plot(range(3, 6), list2)
のようにすればいいということですね．
分かりやすい回答ありがとうございました．

Comment: いえ、それだと `range(0, 6)` の長さが 6 なのに対し `list1` の長さが 5 で異なるのでエラーになるはずです。

Comment: すいません．手元のソースが間違えていました．
この場合はrange(0, 5)ですね．
ありがとうございました．

Comment: 解決して良かったです。もしよろしければ、回答を承認して頂けると嬉しいです :) https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers